# Python - Kivy how to integrate OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, camera, kivy, ip

I have a problem with the combination of opencv and kivy!
I have some code that connects me to my ip cam in python and shows its live stream. This code (without kivy) is working perfectly fine:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import lambdify
from sympy import *
 
 
def connection(host='http://192.168.4.1:81/stream'):
    try:
        urllib.request.urlopen(host)
        return True
    except:
        return False
 
def startlivecamimage():
    if connection():
        stream = urlopen('http://192.168.4.1:81/stream') 
        bytes = b''
        while True: 
            try:
                bytes += stream.read(1024) 
                a = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8') 
                b = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9') 
                if a != -1 and b != -1: 
                    jpg = bytes[a:b+2] 
                    bytes = bytes[b+2:] 
                    getliveimage = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                    livestreamrotated1 = cv2.rotate(getliveimage, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
                    
                cv2.imshow('WeldCam LIVE', livestreamrotated1) 
 
            except Exception as e:
                continue
 
            keyPress = cv2.waitKey(1)
 
startlivecamimage()
```

But when I want to use the same code in combination with a kivy screen and push of a button it is not working anymore:

```
from logging import info
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
import os
import platform
import datetime
import time
import sys
import math
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import threading
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy.core.fromnumeric import repeat
from numpy.core.numeric import False_
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import lambdify
from sympy import *
from datetime import datetime
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.effects.dampedscroll import DampedScrollEffect
from kivy.effects.scroll import ScrollEffect
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.settings import SettingsWithSpinner, SettingItem
from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.effects.scroll import ScrollEffect
from kivy.lang import Builder
import json
 
INTERVAL = 0.01
 
kivy.require("2.0.0")
 
Builder.load_string("""
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
 
<MyScreens>:
    Screen:
        name: 'mainmenuscreen'
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: 1
            orientation: "vertical"
 
            Button:
                text: 'Start IP Camera'
                on_release: 
                    app.ip_camera_schedule()
 
            Button:
                text: 'Quit'
                on_release: root.current = app.exit_software()
""")
 
class MyScreens(ScreenManager):
    pass
 
 
#Program is called "SchweißnahtlehreApp"
class SchweißnahtlehreApp(App):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
 
 
    def build(self):
        myscreenmanager = MyScreens()
        return myscreenmanager
 
    #function to check connection to IP Camera
    def connection(host='http://192.168.4.1:81/stream'):
        try:
            urllib.request.urlopen(host)
            return True
        except:
            return False
 
    def ip_camera_schedule(self):
        if SchweißnahtlehreApp.connection():
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.startipcamera, 0.5)
 
    def startipcamera(self, *args):
        stream = urlopen('http://192.168.4.1:81/stream') 
        bytes = b''
        try:
            print("trying...")
            bytes += stream.read(1024) 
            a = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8') 
            b = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9') 
            if a != -1 and b != -1:
                print("step 1 done")
                jpg = bytes[a:b+2] 
                print("step 2 done")
                bytes = bytes[b+2:] 
                print("step 3 done")
                getliveimage = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                print("step 4 done")
                livestreamrotated1 = cv2.rotate(getliveimage, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
                cv2.imshow('frame', livestreamrotated1)
        except Exception as e:
            print("this did not work")
        keyPress = cv2.waitKey(1)
    
    def exit_software(self):
       App.get_running_app().stop()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    SchweißnahtlehreApp().run()
```

(please don't mind all the imports, I will need them later in my program and didn't want to delete them)

Where is the problem here?
I would like to add at this point:

- I do not really know what these lines do:

```
a = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8') 
b = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9') 
if a != -1 and b != -1:
```

when I change "-1" to "0" it works until "step 3 done" and then takes the Exception.
So it crashes at the "cv2.imdecode.." line.
The code without kivy is working with a/b != -1 AND 0.

The Code with Kivy and a/b != 0 crashes instantly

- The Kivy integration works perfectly fine if I use USB-cam instead of IP-cam:
  That's the reason why I don't think it's a general "kivy+opencv" problem. If I use "cv2.VideoCapture(0)" and my USB camera the integration works fine! But I need the code for IP camera stream...

Thank you in advance for any help!!

Comment: your stream "parsing" is a mess. there is no reason why you should "find" any markers in the stream... maybe once, but not multiple times. a read() on a stream may return fewer bytes than expected, because that's all that arrived yet. you absolutely MUST check and deal with that. whether that gives you more or less data depends on *timing*. *timing* is certainly affected because you use waitKey() AND kivy. read a kivy tutorial to find out how to show images using *kivy* itself. either use OpenCV's imshow+waitkey, or use kivy, but you shouldn't mix that.

Comment: oh and DO NOT open the stream repeatedly. that's just wasteful. I expect the web server sends you MJPEG or some `multipart/x-mixed-replace`. simply don't do this yourself. use an API that reads from the server and gives you a bunch of pictures.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! In the end I will not use imshow and waitkey but integrate the OpenCV as a kivy image...but I need to get the OpenCV image from the IP cam first...and that is the problem at this point. I can not convert it to kivy image if there is no image to convert...

Comment: I completely missed that you said: "I do not really know what these lines do" that's the whole problem... well actually the problem is that you seem unable to figure out what they do *and* you just change them arbitrarily and then wonder why stuff doesn't work. I'd suggest working on both aspects.

Answer (score 0):

A CSDN [blog](https://blog.csdn.net/chen666250/article/details/110186342) use opencv and kivy to show photo.